# Allocate an array and fill it

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to allocate an array of integers, of a certain length, and fill it with a sequence of integers starting at zero.

The values of the array that you return should be 0,1,2,3 ... (that is, each value should match its index).

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++)
 {
    int[] ar = new ar[i];
    return ar[i];
 }

 return 0;
```

I don't understand why this does not work?

Comment: Probably easier to turn the question around - can *you* explain what each of these lines of code does?

Comment: Instead of trying to guess, take the time to study.

Answer (score 0):

You should be declaring the array before the loop, and returning the array after the loop. And, fill the array during the loop. Something like,

```
int[] ar = new ar[len];        // <-- declare the array
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     ar[i] = i;                // <-- fill the array
}
return ar;                     // <-- return the array
```